# Return max of zero or value for a pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace negative values in a pandas DataFrame column with zero.

Is there a more concise way to construct this expression?

```
df['value'][df['value'] < 0] = 0
```

Comment: That looks like how you'd do it in `numpy` ... I doubt there's a more concise way other than breaking it into 2 statements.

Comment: Maybe something like `df['value'] = max((df['value'], 0))`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the canonical way of doing it, while not necessarily more concise, is more flexible (in that you can apply this to arbitrary columns)

```
In [39]: df = DataFrame(randn(5,1),columns=['value'])

In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
      value
0  0.092232
1 -0.472784
2 -1.857964
3 -0.014385
4  0.301531

In [41]: df.loc[df['value']<0,'value'] = 0

In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
      value
0  0.092232
1  0.000000
2  0.000000
3  0.000000
4  0.301531
```

Comment: Much more flexible (and less obscure).

Comment: Though in some respects, the np.clip or np.max solutions are more easily read, I think this is the most precise answer to my original question.

Comment: Would .ix be slightly better than .loc since .ix is the more general form? Or are there arguments in favor of loc over ix? - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix

Comment: This is the slowest method of any answer here, ~7x slower than `np.maximum` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33000983/1840471.

Answer (score 31):

You could use the [clip method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html#pandas-series-clip):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.arange(-5,5)})
df['value'] = df['value'].clip(0, None)
print(df)
```

yields

```
   value
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      1
7      2
8      3
9      4
```

Comment: On a side note, you don't need the `np.inf` as the second argument. It defaults to None, which is equivalent, in this case.  If you're concerned about readability with leaving the second argument out, you could use `df.value.clip_lower(0)` instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, I assumed `pandas.DataFrame.clip` behaved like `numpy` as well. I only realized that it didn't (and you didn't need the second argument) about 5 minutes ago! :)

Comment: @JoeKington: When `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, `df['values']` is a `pandas.Series`, which is a subclass of `ndarray`.

Comment: True, but the `clip` method is different (has default parameters for `lower` and `upper`), and it has additional methods such as `clip_lower` and `clip_upper`.

Comment: @JoeKington: Hm, my pandas appears to be too old then. In version 0.10.0, it inherits from `numpy.clip`.

Comment: It sill behaves similar to `numpy.clip` but it automatically fills in the max or min bounds with the max or min of the data if one of the bounds is left out:  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L1954  As far as I can tell, that's the case for 0.10, as well.

Comment: This answer doesn't achieve what the OP has asked: "Is there a more concise way to construct this expression?" His original formulation is already more concise.

Comment: @JoeKington: Indeed, you are right. I don't know what I was doing this morning that led me to think otherwise...

Comment: This is almost twice as slow as `numpy.maximum`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33000983/1840471.

Answer (score 27):

Another possibility is `numpy.maximum()`. This is more straight-forward to read in my opinion.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['value'] = np.maximum(df.value, 0)
```

It's also significantly faster than all other methods.

```
df_orig = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.arange(-1000000, 1000000)})

df = df_orig.copy()
%timeit df['value'] = np.maximum(df.value, 0)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 8.36 ms per loop

df = df_orig.copy()
%timeit df['value'] = np.where(df.value < 0, 0, df.value)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop

df = df_orig.copy()
%timeit df['value'] = df.value.clip(0, None)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

df = df_orig.copy()
%timeit df['value'] = df.value.clip_lower(0)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 ms per loop

df = df_orig.copy()
%timeit df.loc[df.value < 0, 'value'] = 0
# 10 loops, best of 3: 62.7 ms per loop
```

([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Db_5DeQobuwPSe26WChF4Lw_KWZfxt7V))

Comment: i think this is good, the only bad thing is that `np.max != np.maximum` which makes this bad mnemonically

Comment: @maxymoo I agree, they should have gone with the SQL `GREATEST` name to distinguish.

Comment: Using `np.fmax` and `np.amax` in place of `np.maximum` and `np.max` can help avoid the confusion.

Comment: I like this solution since it resembles the syntax of other statistical programs. For example, `df['week_16'] = np.maximum(df.week-16, 0)`  in Python corresponds with `week_16=max(week - 16, 0);` in SAS or `cd4$week_16 <- pmax(cd4$week -16,0)` in R. If you're coming from packages like this, this is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

Or `where` to check:

```
>>> import pandas as pd,numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,1),columns=['value'])
>>> df
      value
0  1.193313
1 -1.011003
2 -0.399778
3 -0.736607
4 -0.629540
>>> df['value']=df['value'].where(df['value']>0,0)
>>> df
      value
0  1.193313
1  0.000000
2  0.000000
3  0.000000
4  0.000000
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, `np.where` is also a possibility, which is faster than most answers here. The [`np.maximum` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33000983/1840471) is the best approach though, as it's faster and more concise than this.

```
df['value'] = np.where(df.value < 0, 0, df.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take only values greater than zero, leaving those which are negative as NaN (works with frames not with series), then impute.

```
df[df > 0].fillna(0)
```